# How can I solve the error while compiling the linux kernel 2.6.32.8

Tags: linux, kernel

while I was compiling the 2.6.32.8 linux kernel,I got the error message like this:

```
In file included from drivers/net/igbvf/ethtool.c:36:0:
drivers/net/igbvf/igbvf.h: At top level:
drivers/net/igbvf/igbvf.h:128:15: error: duplicate member ‘page’
make[3]: *** [drivers/net/igbvf/ethtool.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [drivers/net/igbvf] Error 2
make[1]: *** [drivers/net] Error 2
make: *** [drivers] Error 2
```

My version of gcc is 4.6.3 and I am using Ubuntu linux (the kernel I am using is 3.2.0.30).I've tried for times but failed,please help!

Answer (score 0):

I've got it done ... or to be exact,I avoided it.
I changed the kernel to be compiled and I changed the version of ubuntu.the kernel 2.6.38.4 can be compiled under ubuntu 10.04 with the kernel 2.6.32 and the gcc 4.4.3